# Bindkey to execute command (Zsh)

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, zle

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) one can do the following:

```
bind -x '"\C-l":ls'
```

to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to external (ie. system's rather than [readline](/questions/tagged/readline) function)

`ls` command to list directory contents.

How to do the same in [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh), and preferably with <kbd>Alt</kbd> (`\M-l`?)

instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as it is seemingly already bound to `clear` to clear the screen.

Answer (score 17):

```
% namingthingsishard () { echo; ls; zle redisplay }
% zle -N namingthingsishard                  
% bindkey '^l' namingthingsishard                  
%
```

This binds <kbd>control+l</kbd> because I don't know what `\M-l` generates for you; running `read -r` and then mashing keys might show something suitable to use with `bindkey`, or run `bindkey` with no arguments to show what is already set. For more information on bindkey and widgets, see [`zshzle(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshzle).

Comment: any idea about `unbind`?

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>CTRL+L</kbd> to run 'ls'

```
bindkey -s "^L" 'ls^M'
```