# How to bind a keyboard shortcut in zsh to a program requiring stdin?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, ranger, zle

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373795/63722): I'm trying to create a keyboard shortcut for the terminal file manager [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger), in order to jump from the zsh prompt into the file manager with a single keystroke. I was following the linked answer, adding this to my `.zshrc`:

```bash
run_ranger () { echo; ranger; zle redisplay }
zle -N run_ranger
bindkey '^f' run_ranger
```

The key binding itself works, however ranger fails to start with `Error: Must run ranger from terminal`. I had a look at the [ranger code (Python)](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/325f41e6a841ab1413020b9d2d86c3922d90f407/ranger/core/main.py#L137) and it performs the common check `sys.stdin.isatty()` to verify that is has a TTY stdin. How can I modify the zle widget so that stdin is properly set?

Comment: Add < $TTY to the ranger command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@llua's comment was indeed the trick to solve the stdin issue, thanks!

My use case required yet another deviation from the linked question. I'm using ranger to change the working directory (using [this trick](https://superuser.com/q/1043806/173159)). In this case the `zle redisplay` has to be replaced by `zle reset-prompt` to properly change the prompt ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52325626/1804173)). The full solution becomes:

```
run_ranger () {
    echo
    ranger --choosedir=$HOME/.rangerdir < $TTY
    LASTDIR=`cat $HOME/.rangerdir`
    cd "$LASTDIR"
    zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N run_ranger
bindkey '^f' run_ranger
```

Comment: `$(< ~/.rangerdir)` should avoid the fork and exec and read and writes of `cat`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be applicable to everyone. But I'm using `tmux` and I just resort to the following:

```bash
tmux send-keys "ranger" Enter
```

It uses `tmux` to send the word `ranger` and then press `Enter`. Ugly I know, but it works.